# Select rows with conditions based on two columns(Start date and end date)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
  id  start_date  end_date
0   1   2017/06/01  2021/05/31
1   2   2018/10/01  2022/09/30
2   3   2015/01/01  2019/02/28
3   4   2017/11/01  2021/10/31
```

Can anyone tell me how i will slice the rows only for the start date which is `2017/06/01` and end date which is `2021/10/31` only.

Comment: Chain conditions with `|` for like `df[df.start_date.eq('2017/06/01') | df.end_date.eq('2021/10/31')]`

Comment: Why this is duplicate?

Comment: Because it is simple check by 2 conditions, solution above not working?